# Want to upgrade project from Angular v5 to Angular v6

Tags: angular, migration, upgrade, angular-ivy

As Angular 6 is here, I want to upgrade or move my angular 5 client application to angular 6, but I'm not getting any tutorial or anything which can guide me through.

According to me I just need to run a new Angular CLI and then have to move my older source to new project. I read the Angular 6 is using a new renderer called Ivy. Will I have to change my project according to Ivy?

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 275, accepted):

## Upgrade from Angular v6 to Angular v7

**Version 7** of Angular has been released [Official Angular blog link](https://blog.angular.io/version-7-of-angular-cli-prompts-virtual-scroll-drag-and-drop-and-more-c594e22e7b8c). Visit official angular update guide https://update.angular.io for detailed information. These steps will work for basic angular 6 apps using Angular Material.

```
ng update @angular/cli 
ng update @angular/core
ng update @angular/material
```

## Upgrade from Angular v5 to Angular v6

**Version 6** of Angular has been released [Official Angular blog link](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4). 
I have mentioned general upgrade steps below, but before and after the update you need to make changes in your code to make it workable in v6, for that detailed information visit official website https://update.angular.io .

Upgrade Steps (largely taken from the [official *Angular Update Guide*](https://update.angular.io/) for a basic Angular app using Angular Material):

1. Make sure NodeJS version is 8.9+ if not update it.
2. Update Angular cli globally and locally, and migrate the old configuration **.angular-cli.json** to the new **angular.json** format by running the following:

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli  
   npm install @angular/cli  
   ng update @angular/cli
   ```
3. Update all of your Angular framework packages to v6,and the correct version 
   of RxJS and TypeScript by running the following:

   ```
   ng update @angular/core
   ```
4. Update Angular Material to the latest version by running the following:

   ```
   ng update @angular/material
   ```
5. RxJS v6 has major changes from v5, v6 brings backwards compatibility package rxjs-compat that will keep your applications working, but you should refactor TypeScript code so that it doesn't depend on rxjs-compat. To refactor TypeScript code run following:

   ```
   npm install -g rxjs-tslint   
   rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
   ```

   Note: Once all of your dependencies have updated to RxJS 6, remove rxjs- 
   compat as it increases bundle size. please see this [RxJS Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) for more info.

   ```
   npm uninstall rxjs-compat
   ```
6. Done run `ng serve` to check it.
   If you get errors in build refer https://update.angular.io for detailed info.

### Upgrade from Angular v5 to Angular 6.0.0-rc.5

1. Upgrade rxjs to 6.0.0-beta.0, please see this [RxJS Upgrade Guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md) for more info. RxJS v6 has breaking change hence first make your code compatible to latest RxJS version.
2. Update NodeJS version to 8.9+ (this is required by angular cli 6 version)
3. Update Angular cli global package to next version.

   ```
   npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   npm cache verify
   ```

   if npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean`

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli@next
   ```
4. Change angular packages versions in package.json file to `^6.0.0-rc.5`

   ```
   "dependencies": {
     "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.0-rc.12",
     "@angular/common": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/core": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/http": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/material": "^6.0.0-rc.12",
     "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/router": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "core-js": "^2.5.5",
     "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
     "rxjs": "^6.0.0-uncanny-rc.7",
     "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-uncanny-rc.7",
     "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.5.0",
     "@angular/cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0-rc.5",
     "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
     "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
     "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
     "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
     "karma": "~1.4.1",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
     "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
     "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
     "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
     "protractor": "~5.1.0",
     "ts-node": "~5.0.0",
     "tslint": "~5.9.1",
     "typescript": "^2.7.2"
   }
   ```
5. Next update Angular cli local package to next version and install above mentioned packages.

   ```
   rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows 
   Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
   npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@next
   npm install
   ```
6. The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed from angular cli 6.0.0-rc.2 version, and your existing configuration can be updated automatically by running the following command. It will remove old config file **.angular-cli.json** and will write new **angular.json** file.

   `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4`

Note :- If you get following error "The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=2.7.2 and <2.8.0 but 2.8.3 was found instead". run following command :

```
npm install typescript@2.7.2
```

Comment: https://update.angular.io/ does not work in Edge at this time. It loads OK, but once you start to use it a bit it causes some kind of problem that causes the page not to respond and the browser to ask if you would like to recover the page.

Comment: Step 5 I'm getting `bash: rxjs-5-to-6-migrate: command not found`. Any thoughts?

Comment: when i run `ng update @angular/core` in my ionic project folder, I get error `Invalid range: "*"`

Comment: After all above steps I was getting this stupid issue: Could not find module `"@angular-devkit/build-angular"` from... So that fixed by `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --save-dev`. Other than that I had to update libraries that were using previous rxjs-compat, like `ng update @ngx-translate/core`, `ng update @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`, because few of them wasn't properly updated.

Comment: This command : ng update @angular/cli ,did not work but this worked instead : ncu -u

Comment: if you receive "Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.8) is greater than your local
version (1.6.8). The local Angular CLI version is used." use npm install @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 20):

Angular 6 has just been released.

https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Here is what worked for one of my smaller projects

1. npm install -g @angular/cli
2. npm install @angular/cli
3. ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.0
4. ng update @angular/core
5. npm install rxjs-compat
6. ng serve

You might need to update your run scripts in package.json
For eg. if you use flags like "app" and "environment"
These have been updated to "project" and "configuration" respectively.

Refer https://update.angular.io/ for more detailed guide.

Comment: After step 2 I had to convert the following .json files (tsconfig, angular-cli.json, tslint) to UTF8, without BOM. I got an Invalid JSON character error at that step.

Answer (score 16):

Just use the official upgrade guide which will tell you what you need to do for your own particular needs:

[image: Upgrade angular]

https://update.angular.io/

Comment: this should realy be the accepted answer as it answers all other upgrade questions

Answer (score 8):

Check the step by step upgrade details from Angular 5 to Angular 6. These provides details on issues you encounter during upgrade and how to resolve them.

- Update your node version to 8 or above and Install Angular cli latest
  globally by npm i -g @angular/cli@latest.
- Angular 6 uses angular.json as configuration file instead of .anguar-cli.json. Also tslint has been changed. Check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace for
  latest configuration details. You have to move any of your existing
  configuration to new configuration file.
- To do this create another
  dummy project with latest cli using ng new ‘your-project’ and same
  defaults such as prefix, style etc you used earlier for your project.
  Create new project with cli
  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/new
- Use
  https://update.angular.io/ to check what has been changed from your
  current version of Angular → Angular 6. It provides usage of how to
  change/fix them.
- Follow the steps above and copy/update the
  angular.json file created in step2. Do npm i in your project to get
  all dependencies and do npm update
- Now comes the big part. RxJS
  upgrade and resolving conflicts. RxJS has standardised imports of
  operators and Observable creators with this release. Do npm i -g
  rxjs-tslint and add below lint configuration in tslint.json

```js
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/rxjs-tslint"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "rxjs-collapse-imports": true,
    "rxjs-pipeable-operators-only": true,
    "rxjs-no-static-observable-methods": true,
    "rxjs-proper-imports": true
  }
}
```

- Now run ng lint --fix. This fixes few items but most of the remaining issues will be highlighted and you have to fix it manually.

**Operators Name change:**

```
do -> tap, 
catch -> catchError, 
switch -> switchAll, 
finally -> finalize
```

**All operators moved to rxjs/operators**

```
import { map, filter, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Observable creation methods are moved to rxjs**

```
   import { Observable, Subject, of, from } from 'rxjs';
```

*You are all set. Welcome to Angular 6 :)*
[Check my blog post here on how to upgrade](https://medium.com/@uday4vunnam/things-i-learned-in-upgrading-to-angular-6-277e4c9ec516)

Answer (score 4):

I had to re-run **ng update @angular/cli** for angular-cli.json to be changed to angular.json

Answer (score 2):

#### *Complete guide*

## -----------------With angular-cli--------------------------

## 1. Update CLI globally and locally

1. Using NPM ( make sure that you have node version 8+ )

   `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   npm cache clean
   npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   npm i @angular/cli --save`
2. Using Yarn

   `yarn remove @angular/cli
   yarn global add @angular/cli
   yarn add @angular/cli`

## 2.Update dependencies

```
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
ng update @angular/material
ng update rxjs
```

#### Angular 6 now depends on TypeScript 2.7 and RxJS 6

Normally that would mean that you have to update your code everywhere RxJS imports and operators are used, but thankfully there’s a package that takes care of most of the heavy lifting:

```
npm i -g rxjs-tslint 

//or using yarn

yarn global add rxjs-tslint
```

Then you can run rxjs-5-to-6-migrate

```
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

finally remove rxjs-compat

```
npm uninstall rxjs-compat

// or using Yarn

yarn remove rxjs-compat
```

---

Refer to this link https://alligator.io/angular/angular-6/

---

## -------------------Without angular-cli-------------------------

So you have to manually update your `package.json` file.

[image: package.json screenshoot of upgrade packages]

Then run

```
 npm update
 npm install --save rxjs-compat
 npm i -g rxjs-tslint
 rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

Comment: I'm getting `bash: rxjs-5-to-6-migrate: command not found` when trying to run the rxjs-5-to-6-migrate command. Any thoughts?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire did you run npm install -g rxjs-tslint

Comment: Yup no idea what it its @Joe

Comment: maybe you don't have latest tslint?

Comment: Do you know how to do this without using angular cli? In my project I do everything manually

Comment: I added a question because the migration tool doesn't seem to be functioning, but got downvoted. I'm updating everything manually.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240220/rxjs-5-to-6-migrate-cannot-find-any-possible-migrations

Comment: @Daniel I hv updated my answer. So that you can upgrade manually.

Comment: When run rxjs-5-to-6-migrate command, I got 'cannot find any possible migration'. What this line means

Answer (score 2):

**Please run the below comments to update to Angular 6 from Angular 5**

1. ng update @angular/cli
2. ng update @angular/core
3. npm install rxjs-compat (In order to support older version rxjs 5.6 )
4. npm install -g rxjs-tslint (To change from rxjs 5 to rxjs 6 format in code. Install globally then only will work)
5. rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json (After installing we have to change it in our source code to rxjs6 format)
6. npm uninstall rxjs-compat (Remove this finally)

Answer (score 1):

As Vinay Kumar pointed out that it will not update global installed Angular CLI. To update it globally just use following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Note if you want to update existing project you have to modify existing project, you should change *package.json*  inside your project.

There are no breaking changes in Angular itself but they are in RxJS, so don't forget to use rxjs-compat library to work with legacy code.

```
  npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

I wrote a good article about installation/updating Angular CLI http://bmnteam.com/angular-cli-installation/

Answer (score 0):

simply run the following command:

`ng update`

note: this will not update globally.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make it work.

My Environment:

Angular CLI Global : 6.0.0, Local: 1.7.4, Angular: 5.2, Typescript 2.5.3

> Note:  To enable `ng Update` you need to install Angular CLI 6.0 first 
>   `npm install -g @angular/cli or npm install @angular/cli`

1. `ng update  //update Angular Package core/common/complier... to 6.0.0`
2. `ng update @angular/cli    //change angular-cli.json to angular.json`

optional if you have angular-material 5.4.2, ngx-translate 9.1.1, ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 1.1.1:

3. `ng update @angular/material  //upgrade to 6.0.1`
4. `npm install @ngx-translate/core@10.0.1 --save   //upgrade ngX translate to 10.0.1 for Angular 6`

5 `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@2.0.0  //for ng-bootstrap`

If you use Observable and get the error:

`ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'. node_modules/rxjs/observable/of.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/observable/of'.`

Change: `import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"; import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

To

`import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";`

Angular CLI issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10621

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps to upgrade 2/4/5 to Angular 6.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

To fix the issue related to "angular.json" :-

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

Store MIGRATION
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#ngrxstore

RXJS MIGRATION
https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Hoping this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this first

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

if got error try this

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b74n.png)