# Migration from angular 5 to angular 6 - changes in @angular/core

Tags: angular, web, angular-cli, angular-animations

I've upgraded my project from angular 5.2.9 to angular 6.0.0-rc.5.

Except few quick RxJS fixes in the packages path, all looks good.
(This link was quiet helpful : [Want to upgrade project from Angular 5 to Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970553/want-to-upgrade-project-from-angular-5-to-angular-6))

But, for some reason i'm encountering a issue with the AnimationEntryMetadata inside the @angular/core module.

I was importing:

```
import {AnimationEntryMetadata} from '@angular/core';
```

In order to create animations. But now i'm getting the following error:

**Module ../node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'AnimationEntryMetadata'**

**Did anybody encounter this issue has well?**

I compared the two @angular/core files between the two versions and found some changes (marked in different color for each version), you can see that the 
"AnimationEntryMetadata" is missing in the newer version:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Symbols related to angular animations now have to be imported from `@angular/animations`.

This change was introduced in the new version.

Furthermore, it seems that the symbol you are referring to was removed and replaced by `AnimationTriggerMetadata`.

Answer (score 4):

[Please refer this link - Angular 6 package change](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular-6-features/#angular6-rc3)

To give the support to angular 6 ,Angular 5 packages are moved to the new package.

Answer (score 3):

From Angular 4+ it is AnimationTriggerMetadata and not AnimationEntryMetadata