# Angular 6 Migration -.angular-cli.json to angular.json

Tags: angular

I've upgraded my project to Angular 6, and everything went fine except the conversion of `.angular-cli.json` file. From the guide I followed, it was said that this will convert it automatically.

> npm install -g @angular/cli
>
> npm install @angular/cli
>
> ng update @angular/cli

However, it was not the case as I still have the old `.angular-cli.json`

Is there a way to do it automatically / manually?

Comment: You need to rename it manually

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://update.angular.io/)?

Comment: Don't rename the file.  It gets deleted and recreated when you follow the guide. If you rename it, then follow the guide, it won't work.

Comment: I had no luck with the answers below; for me, specifying both `--from` and `--to` did the trick. Admittedly I was updating many packages in the migration process, lots of things could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Most likely there were errors in one of those commands. For me, I had to run `npm install -g @angular-devkit/core` first and then run the commands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

npm install @angular/cli
```

In the console output of `npm install @angular/cli` you should see:

```
================================================================================
The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing configuration can
be updated automatically by running the following command:

  ng update @angular/cli
================================================================================
```

Then you obviously should run `ng update @angular/cli` to finish off the process.

See the [Official Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) for additional details.

Comment: There was an error with npm install @angular/cli ng update, I had to re run it and it worked :)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire : I followed the same process, But when I run the command npm install @angular/cli , I got the below error.
npm WARN @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.52 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.17 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.0.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: What I was missing was the `@angular-devkit/core` package, installing that done the trick.

Answer (score 92):

you can automatically update your existing `angular-cli.json` file to `angular.json` file by using the below command provided that you are on v6.x.x or greater of angular cli command line tool.

```
ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --to=6 --migrate-only
```

In the above command `1.7.4` is the previous cli version you were using. The `--migrate-only` flag makes sure that it will only perform a migration but does not update the installed version. Use `--to` instead of `@angular/cli@6` because of https://github.com/angular/angular-update-guide/issues/64.

read more: [angular/cli-github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update)

Comment: Hey, I tried multiple options but your solutions worked. My angular-cli.json is converted to angular.json. But I got another error when I start my application : ng serve
Error : ERROR in src/app/workflows/workflow-list/workflow-list.component.ts(441,4): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: Finally this is what worked for me! I had tried so many solutions including all others here as well as the official angular update guide, but whenever I ran `ng update @angular/cli` it never updated angular-cli.json to angular.json. Finally, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried the above command. Don't know why its not working for me. is there any other command which i can try.

Answer (score 42):

Try running "**ng update @angular/cli**" twice 
it will update angular-cli.json to angular.json

**UPDATE:**

if getting errors like this:

> ERROR: The specified command update is invalid, for available options see
>   ng-help.

then you need to run 2 commands as follows

1. npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest.
2. ng update @angular/cli

this will automatically create angular.json, delete .angular-cli.json and update karma.conf.js, src/tsconfig.spec.json, package.json, and tslint.json

[image]

Answer (score 29):

I was trying to update from 5.2 -> 6.1 and was running into an issue where after running `npm install @angular/cli@6` followed by `ng update @angular/cli@6`, (as described by https://update.angular.io/#5.2:6.1) my `package.json` was being updated but none of the other files like `.angular-cli.json` or `tsconfig.json` were, even though I received no errors. I tried executing the update command multiple times but this had no effect.

I ended up running the following 3 commands which worked for me:

```
npm install @angular/cli@6
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core@6
```

The only real change there is the second command. The document says to run `ng update @angular/cli@6` but that wouldn't update any of the config files.

Answer (score 3):

For upgrading version from 5.2 to 6.0 , I  followed up the following steps.

- Install Node 8 or above.
- yarn global add @angular/cli.
- yarn add @angular/cli.
- ng update @angular/cli.
- ng update @angular/core.

  Note: if, after executing  *ng update @angular/core* command,*invalid range* issue arises,then follow below, just replace the *major version* in package.json, it'll automatically replace the minor.
  Resource : 
  [Want to upgrade project from Angular v5 to Angular v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970553/want-to-upgrade-project-from-angular-v5-to-angular-v6)

  ```
    - npm uninstall -g angular-cli
    - npm cache clean or npm cache verify
    - npm install -g @angular/cli@next
    - then, replace lower versions to higher versions in package.json 
      file.
    - delete node modules folder.
    - run npm/yarn install.
  ```

After *npm install*, if you get error of missing src/styles path, then remove the paths given  in angular.json file under assets block  from  ["src/styles", "src/fonts", "src/images", "src/assets", "src/favicon.ico"] to  ["assets","favicon.ico"].

- yarn global add rxjs-tslint (might required).
- rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json (might required).
- yarn install @angular/material@6.0.0 (to update material packages).

=> **Please note** you never need to rename *angular.cli.json* to *angular.json* manually!!

** feel free to ask if further queries arises.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow these steps :

1) Update your Angular CLI globally and locally (assuming latest version to be 7)

2) Take your old project and run following command

- npm install @angular/cli
- ng update @angular/cli

After running this you have updated all your angular packages to the latest version.

3)Add this package as it is still missing

npm install  @angular-devkit/core --save -dev

4) create a fresh new project with ng serve (latest version)

5) Create a new empty file with name angular.json and copy the content of angular.json from the new project into it.

6) Update the name of project accordingly in angular.json

7) Run npm install

8) Run ng serve

9) You are now ready with the latest version of angular.

I followed the above steps to migrate from angular2 to angular7.

Comment: In case you are getting an error in running ng serve, check the error if it is most probably the entries in angular.json, update them accordingly. For ex - project name, filepaths etc.

Answer (score 0):

**IN CASE OF:**
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
**OR**
The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

**Upgrade/downgrade to the desired version ( I tried Angular 6 for example )**

```
[sudo] npm install -g -f @angular/cli@6.1.4
```

**Update the local project**

```
ng update @angular/cli@6.1.4
```

**And you're good to go :)**

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to actually commit every changes or stash them before I could run the command to update the cli as shown in this screenshot.

I did these commands:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest 

ng update@angular/cli
```

And committing the changes between these two. 
[image: Ng serve]

Answer (score 0):

This steps will help you create angular.json.I had angular 4 and it worked for me.It should work for older versions.

1. Create a **ng-update-v6.js** file inside the Angular project's folder and add the following code given in [gist](https://gist.github.com/leo6104/b4a2da0863d3c5b1877860d62464c706)
2. Run
   `node ng-update-v6.js .angular-cli.json`
3. Now you have angular.json.
4. Update Package.json `ncu -u`
5. Install Updated Node Modules `npm i`
6. If you face polyfills import issue (change polyfills.ts)

from

```
import "core-js/es5/reflect";
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
```

to

```
import "core-js/es/reflect";
```

Credit goes to:[Article](https://www.techiediaries.com/convert-angular-cli-json-to-angular-json/)