# The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found in Angular 4

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-audit

I have cloned one of my old project from github and tried to install `node_module` and found some vulnerabilities. To fix them I ran the following command

```
npm audit fix
```

there were still some more vulnerabilities, so I ran the forced fix command

```
npm audit fix --force
```

After that when I am trying to run the project I am getting this -

[image: Error]

> The Serve command requires to be run in an Angular Projects, but  a project definition could not be found.

Comment: Which version of Angular does it use, and which version of Angular CLI have you got installed globally?

Comment: I have got version 7.0.6 installed globally

Comment: Does your angular project contain an `angular.json` file at the root, or the older `angular-cli.json` file?

Comment: abgular-cli.json file

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the command in the application root folder

Comment: The new version of `angular cli` requires an `angular.json` file instead.

Comment: @DayOne yes i am running the command in root folder

Comment: @user184994 thanks for the hints.I have successfully fixed the issue follwoing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232874/angular-6-migration-angular-cli-json-to-angular-json)

Answer (score 4):

the reason is that the new @angular/cli form version 7, have an angular.json file instead of angular-cli.json in version 1.x.x
you can fix that by running:

`ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=<Your_Angular_CLI_Old_Version>`

it will replace angular-cli.json file by the new file

Answer (score 1):

If you run **ng serve -o** in a command line as an administrator,
you must insure that you are in the sub directory where your package.json
is located, otherwise you will be encountered of such error message...

Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that When you edit a component.cs/ component.html or any pages that are in your project and trying to run the project from different location of your project.
So, go to your project folder and run the project using the command "ng serve"