# how to convert angular-cli.json to angular.json

Tags: angular-cli-v7

when running "ng test" angular cli throws error

"The test command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found."

> npm install @angular/cli

ng test

wants to convert angular-cli.json to angular.json

Comment: Run `ng update` on the project. That should convert the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76280579/12429704

Answer (score 0):

Update Angular cli globally and locally, and migrate the old configuration .angular-cli.json to the new angular.json format by running the following:

npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli