# NPM Install Failing Unable to Execute Ng Build Angular App

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an Angular 2 app I've dusted off and am wanting to fix some performance issues. I added webpack and webpack-cli to my package.json file using npm install.  However when I run:

```
npm install
```

I get the following error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'build' target, and the project name is 'undefined'. See "C:\Users\cmazz\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-sQvx2f\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

**angular-errors.log**

```
[error] Error: No projects support the 'build' target.
    at BuildCommand.initialize (C:\Users\cmazz\Sites\base-angular-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:58:19)
    at async BuildCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\cmazz\Sites\base-angular-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:127:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (C:\Users\cmazz\Sites\base-angular-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:204:24)
    at async default_1 (C:\Users\cmazz\Sites\base-angular-app\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:80:31)
```

**architecht-command.js**

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.ArchitectCommand = void 0;
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that can be
 * found in the LICENSE file at https://angular.io/license
 */
const architect_1 = require("@angular-devkit/architect");
const node_1 = require("@angular-devkit/architect/node");
const core_1 = require("@angular-devkit/core");
const json_schema_1 = require("../utilities/json-schema");
const analytics_1 = require("./analytics");
const command_1 = require("./command");
const parser_1 = require("./parser");
class ArchitectCommand extends command_1.Command {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.useReportAnalytics = false;
        // If this command supports running multiple targets.
        this.multiTarget = false;
    }
    async initialize(options) {
        await super.initialize(options);
        this._registry = new core_1.json.schema.CoreSchemaRegistry();
        this._registry.addPostTransform(core_1.json.schema.transforms.addUndefinedDefaults);
        this._registry.useXDeprecatedProvider(msg => this.logger.warn(msg));
        if (!this.workspace) {
            throw new Error('A workspace is required for an architect command.');
        }
        this._architectHost = new node_1.WorkspaceNodeModulesArchitectHost(this.workspace, this.workspace.basePath);
        this._architect = new architect_1.Architect(this._architectHost, this._registry);
        if (!this.target) {
            if (options.help) {
                // This is a special case where we just return.
                return;
            }
            const specifier = this._makeTargetSpecifier(options);
            if (!specifier.project || !specifier.target) {
                throw new Error('Cannot determine project or target for command.');
            }
            return;
        }
        let projectName = options.project;
        if (projectName && !this.workspace.projects.has(projectName)) {
            throw new Error(`Project '${projectName}' does not exist.`);
        }
        const commandLeftovers = options['--'];
        const targetProjectNames = [];
        for (const [name, project] of this.workspace.projects) {
            if (project.targets.has(this.target)) {
                targetProjectNames.push(name);
            }
        }
        if (targetProjectNames.length === 0) {
          throw new Error(this.missingTargetError || `No projects support the '${this.target}' target, and the project name is '${projectName}'` );
        }
        if (projectName && !targetProjectNames.includes(projectName)) {
            throw new Error(this.missingTargetError ||
                `Project '${projectName}' does not support the '${this.target}' target.`);
        }
        if (!projectName && commandLeftovers && commandLeftovers.length > 0) {
            const builderNames = new Set();
            const leftoverMap = new Map();
            let potentialProjectNames = new Set(targetProjectNames);
            for (const name of targetProjectNames) {
                const builderName = await this._architectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget({
                    project: name,
                    target: this.target,
                });
                if (this.multiTarget) {
                    builderNames.add(builderName);
                }
                const builderDesc = await this._architectHost.resolveBuilder(builderName);
                const optionDefs = await json_schema_1.parseJsonSchemaToOptions(this._registry, builderDesc.optionSchema);
                const parsedOptions = parser_1.parseArguments([...commandLeftovers], optionDefs);
                const builderLeftovers = parsedOptions['--'] || [];
                leftoverMap.set(name, { optionDefs, parsedOptions });
                potentialProjectNames = new Set(builderLeftovers.filter(x => potentialProjectNames.has(x)));
            }
            if (potentialProjectNames.size === 1) {
                projectName = [...potentialProjectNames][0];
                // remove the project name from the leftovers
                const optionInfo = leftoverMap.get(projectName);
                if (optionInfo) {
                    const locations = [];
                    let i = 0;
                    while (i < commandLeftovers.length) {
                        i = commandLeftovers.indexOf(projectName, i + 1);
                        if (i === -1) {
                            break;
                        }
                        locations.push(i);
                    }
                    delete optionInfo.parsedOptions['--'];
                    for (const location of locations) {
                        const tempLeftovers = [...commandLeftovers];
                        tempLeftovers.splice(location, 1);
                        const tempArgs = parser_1.parseArguments([...tempLeftovers], optionInfo.optionDefs);
                        delete tempArgs['--'];
                        if (JSON.stringify(optionInfo.parsedOptions) === JSON.stringify(tempArgs)) {
                            options['--'] = tempLeftovers;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!projectName && this.multiTarget && builderNames.size > 1) {
                throw new Error(core_1.tags.oneLine `
          Architect commands with command line overrides cannot target different builders. The
          '${this.target}' target would run on projects ${targetProjectNames.join()} which have the
          following builders: ${'\n  ' + [...builderNames].join('\n  ')}
        `);
            }
        }
        if (!projectName && !this.multiTarget) {
            const defaultProjectName = this.workspace.extensions['defaultProject'];
            if (targetProjectNames.length === 1) {
                projectName = targetProjectNames[0];
            }
            else if (defaultProjectName && targetProjectNames.includes(defaultProjectName)) {
                projectName = defaultProjectName;
            }
            else if (options.help) {
                // This is a special case where we just return.
                return;
            }
            else {
                throw new Error(this.missingTargetError || 'Cannot determine project or target for command.');
            }
        }
        options.project = projectName;
        const builderConf = await this._architectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget({
            project: projectName || (targetProjectNames.length > 0 ? targetProjectNames[0] : ''),
            target: this.target,
        });
        const builderDesc = await this._architectHost.resolveBuilder(builderConf);
        this.description.options.push(...(await json_schema_1.parseJsonSchemaToOptions(this._registry, builderDesc.optionSchema)));
        // Update options to remove analytics from options if the builder isn't safelisted.
        for (const o of this.description.options) {
            if (o.userAnalytics && !analytics_1.isPackageNameSafeForAnalytics(builderConf)) {
                o.userAnalytics = undefined;
            }
        }
    }
    async run(options) {
        return await this.runArchitectTarget(options);
    }
    async runSingleTarget(target, targetOptions) {
        // We need to build the builderSpec twice because architect does not understand
        // overrides separately (getting the configuration builds the whole project, including
        // overrides).
        const builderConf = await this._architectHost.getBuilderNameForTarget(target);
        const builderDesc = await this._architectHost.resolveBuilder(builderConf);
        const targetOptionArray = await json_schema_1.parseJsonSchemaToOptions(this._registry, builderDesc.optionSchema);
        const overrides = parser_1.parseArguments(targetOptions, targetOptionArray, this.logger);
        const allowAdditionalProperties = typeof builderDesc.optionSchema === 'object' && builderDesc.optionSchema.additionalProperties;
        if (overrides['--'] && !allowAdditionalProperties) {
            (overrides['--'] || []).forEach(additional => {
                this.logger.fatal(`Unknown option: '${additional.split(/=/)[0]}'`);
            });
            return 1;
        }
        await this.reportAnalytics([this.description.name], {
            ...await this._architectHost.getOptionsForTarget(target),
            ...overrides,
        });
        const run = await this._architect.scheduleTarget(target, overrides, {
            logger: this.logger,
            analytics: analytics_1.isPackageNameSafeForAnalytics(builderConf) ? this.analytics : undefined,
        });
        const { error, success } = await run.output.toPromise();
        await run.stop();
        if (error) {
            this.logger.error(error);
        }
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }
    async runArchitectTarget(options) {
        const extra = options['--'] || [];
        try {
            const targetSpec = this._makeTargetSpecifier(options);
            if (!targetSpec.project && this.target) {
                // This runs each target sequentially.
                // Running them in parallel would jumble the log messages.
                let result = 0;
                for (const project of this.getProjectNamesByTarget(this.target)) {
                    result |= await this.runSingleTarget({ ...targetSpec, project }, extra);
                }
                return result;
            }
            else {
                return await this.runSingleTarget(targetSpec, extra);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof core_1.schema.SchemaValidationException) {
                const newErrors = [];
                for (const schemaError of e.errors) {
                    if (schemaError.keyword === 'additionalProperties') {
                        const unknownProperty = schemaError.params.additionalProperty;
                        if (unknownProperty in options) {
                            const dashes = unknownProperty.length === 1 ? '-' : '--';
                            this.logger.fatal(`Unknown option: '${dashes}${unknownProperty}'`);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    newErrors.push(schemaError);
                }
                if (newErrors.length > 0) {
                    this.logger.error(new core_1.schema.SchemaValidationException(newErrors).message);
                }
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
    getProjectNamesByTarget(targetName) {
        const allProjectsForTargetName = [];
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-non-null-assertion
        for (const [name, project] of this.workspace.projects) {
            if (project.targets.has(targetName)) {
                allProjectsForTargetName.push(name);
            }
        }
        if (this.multiTarget) {
            // For multi target commands, we always list all projects that have the target.
            return allProjectsForTargetName;
        }
        else {
            // For single target commands, we try the default project first,
            // then the full list if it has a single project, then error out.
            // tslint:disable-next-line: no-non-null-assertion
            const maybeDefaultProject = this.workspace.extensions['defaultProject'];
            if (maybeDefaultProject && allProjectsForTargetName.includes(maybeDefaultProject)) {
                return [maybeDefaultProject];
            }
            if (allProjectsForTargetName.length === 1) {
                return allProjectsForTargetName;
            }
            throw new Error(`Could not determine a single project for the '${targetName}' target.`);
        }
    }
    _makeTargetSpecifier(commandOptions) {
        let project, target, configuration;
        if (commandOptions.target) {
            [project, target, configuration] = commandOptions.target.split(':');
            if (commandOptions.configuration) {
                configuration = commandOptions.configuration;
            }
        }
        else {
            project = commandOptions.project;
            target = this.target;
            if (commandOptions.prod) {
                // The --prod flag will always be the first configuration, available to be overwritten
                // by following configurations.
                configuration = 'production';
            }
            if (commandOptions.configuration) {
                configuration =
                    `${configuration ? `${configuration},` : ''}${commandOptions.configuration}`;
            }
        }
        if (!project) {
            project = '';
        }
        if (!target) {
            target = '';
        }
        return {
            project,
            configuration: configuration || '',
            target,
        };
    }
}
exports.ArchitectCommand = ArchitectCommand;
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "blogapp"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Does anyone know the problem here?
I'd appreciate it.
Ironman

Comment: You may want to post some of the `angular.json` file as well, so we can see that. This problem seems like it has to do with the fact that there is no `build` architect within your Angular project.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi thanks for responding and trying to help.  I just posted the angular-cli.json code...

Comment: which version are you running? depending on your cli version & angular versions, you may need to upgrade the `angular-cli.json` to an `angular.json` file. See here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/50232874/4914803) for info about that.