# Angular upgrade from 5 to 6 - Angular.json not created

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm following the official guide to upgrade angular app to version 10 , currently while try to upgrade to CLI version 6 as per the **update.angular.io**

Make sure you are using Node 8 or later
Update your Angular CLI locally, and migrate the configuration to the new angular.json format by
running the following:

```
npm install @angular/cli@6
ng update @angular/cli@6
```

I've run the following code but still i could see .angular-cli.json file instead of angular.json file.

Below is current cli version updated to version 6 except for couple of warning related to peer dependency didnt get any error while updating CLI.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50232874/angular-6-migration-angular-cli-json-to-angular-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick !! **@Andrew Allen** but the second most voted answer worked in my case =>
you can automatically update your existing angular-cli.json file to angular.json file by using the below command provided that you are on v6.x.x or greater of angular cli command line tool.

```
**ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --migrate-only**
```

In the above command 1.7.4 is the previous cli version you were using. The --migrate-only flag makes sure that it will only perform a migration but does not update the installed version.