# ngx-chart error "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Tags: angular5, ngx-charts

I am trying to implements some statistics in my develepping platform and I try to use ngx-charts to display them. However I get an error and I can't figure out why.

I am using storedProcedures for MySQL statistics which I call from Java Restful Backend and return them in Angular 5 front-end. The returned table has the following two fields: Date and number of incidents per day. So the table returned by the backend has those two columns.

My code for the component rendering the chart is the following:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {StatisticsService} from '../../statistics.service';


class Data {

  private _name: string;
  private _value: number;

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

  get value(): number {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(value: number) {
    this._value = value;
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-daily-incidents-statistics',
  templateUrl: './daily-incidents-statistics.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./daily-incidents-statistics.component.css']
})


export class DailyIncidentsStatisticsComponent implements OnInit {


  view: any[] = [700, 400];
  data: any[] = [];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = false;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Ημέρα';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Αρ. Περιστατικών';


  constructor(private statisticsService: StatisticsService) {
    // Object.assign(this, { single })
    // Object.assign(this, { data } );
  }

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };


  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    console.log('NG ON INIT EXECUTION');
    await this.getIncidentsByDay();
  }

  getIncidentsByDay() {
    this.statisticsService.getIncidentsByDay()
      .subscribe(
        (results) => {
          let temp = new Data();

          for (let i in results) {
            console.log(results[i][0] + '>>=====>> ' + results[i][1]);
            temp.name = results[i][0];
            temp.value = results[i][1];
            this.data.push(temp);
          }

          const test = this.data;
          // for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
          //   console.log('wtf: ' + this.data[i][0] + '::::' + this.data[i][1]);
          // }
          // console.log(results);
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
          // Object.assign(this, {test});
        }
      );
  }

}
```

However when I run the above code I get in JavaScript console the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at BarVerticalComponent../src/common/base-chart.component.ts.BaseChartComponent.bindWindowResizeEvent (index.js:7818)
    at BarVerticalComponent../src/common/base-chart.component.ts.BaseChartComponent.ngAfterViewInit (index.js:7730)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:12689)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (core.js:12656)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (core.js:12639)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13794)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14136)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14068)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13791)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14136)
```

My Html Template File:

```
<div>
  lalalal <br/>
  ante pali... <br/>
  kala ti na pw... <br/>
  Gamiete pali... <br/>
  <ngx-charts-bar-vertical
    [view]="view"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [results]="data"
    [gradient]="gradient"
    [xAxis]="showXAxis"
    [yAxis]="showYAxis"
    [legend]="showLegend"
    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
    [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
    (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
</div>
```

While the service for retreiving the values is:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ErrorHandler} from '../shared/lib/error-handler';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class StatisticsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  public getIncidentsByDay(): Observable<any> {
    console.log("FEtching Incidents All By Day");
    const url = 'statistics/incidents/day';
    return this.http.get(url)
      .pipe(catchError(ErrorHandler.handleError));
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using Angular version 5.3 and ngx-charts 8.0 which is compatible with Angular 6 and not Angular 5. I installed ngx-charts version 7.4 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem for me by downgrading to version 7.3.0

`yarn add @swimlane/ngx-charts@7.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the same with `ngx-charts-bar-horizontal`, whereas before this was not the case.  The documentation page seems to be broken at the moment as well, so I assume the software has recently been updated in a broken way.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the  8.0 version, you can upgrade to angular 6 to solve the problem. Here is how you can do the upgrade from v5 to v6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49474334

You can also think that the documention page is broken by now but ou can find it here https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/v/docs-test/installing