# Migrating from Angular5 to Angular6, angular.json is not updated

Tags: json, node.js, angular, angular-cli

I would like to migrate from Angular5 to Angular6, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49474334)

I tried to execute this three commands, to update **.angular-cli.json** to **angular.json**:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

Unfortunately, there is still no **angular.json**. If I try to run `ng serve`, I get this error:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
```

So I renamed **.angular-cli.json** to **angular.json**. But it did not help:

> Schema validation failed with the following errors:   Data path ""
>   should NOT have additional properties(project). Error: Schema
>   validation failed with the following errors:   Data path "" should NOT
>   have additional properties(project).
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._registry.compile.pipe.operators_1.concatMap.validatorResult
>   [as project]
>   (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:173:42)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:122:27)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:112:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:141:26)
>       at InnerSubscriber._next (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\InnerSubscriber.js:30:21)
>       at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:92:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:103:18)
>       at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (C:\projects\my-app\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:122:26)

Therefore I tried to run `ng update @angular/core`, but I get this error:

> Workspace needs to be loaded before it is used.

What do I wrong?

Comment: its asking for `angular.json`, not `.angular.json`

Comment: Check if the versions are updated in package.json.
Also did you try reloading your workspace, esp if you are using VSC as your editor.

Comment: I use notepad++ as editor. I get the `Workspace needs to be loaded` error even if the name of the file is without the dot

Comment: i dont think you need to manually change the file name _.angular.cli.json_ to _angular.json_. Once you update and if its successful automatically the configuration should migrate from _.angular.cli.json_ to _angular.json_.
Check if the versions are updated in package.json and run npm install once.
This can of some help for you - [Angular Update](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: It is not mentioned anywhere to change the file name. But even with the new name, I get the `Workspace needs to be loaded` error

Comment: did you check the versions in _package.json_ if @angualr/cli is updated and tried _npm install_?.

Comment: I have angular/cli 6 in my package.json

Answer (score 6):

You can't manually rename the file .angular-cli.json into angular.json. They have different schemas hence your errors.

Delete the existing dir node_modules. Make sure you run `npm install @angular/cli` and `ng update @angular/cli` from the root dir of your project. If the file angular.json is not created, read the output on the console - it should give you some errors.

If this doesn't help, just generate a new project using Angular CLI 6 and copy the src dir and assets from your existing project into the newly generated one.

I blogged about my experience of upgrading Angular 5 projects to Angular 6 here: https://yakovfain.com/2018/05/16/how-i-migrated-a-dozen-of-projects-to-angular-6