# Angular Upgrade from v5 to v6: core_1.isJsonObject is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to update my angular version from version 5 to v6.
I am basically following the guide here: [Want to upgrade project from Angular v5 to Angular v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970553/want-to-upgrade-project-from-angular-v5-to-angular-v6) and https://update.angular.io/.

I upgraded my node version to v8.9.0 and Angular Cli to latest 6.2.3.

But when I try to run the command: ng update @angular/cli

it fails with error:

> core_1.isJsonObject is not a function TypeError: core_1.isJsonObject
>   is not a function    at Object.parseSchema
>   (C:\Users\project\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\json-schema.js:101:42

I tried doing google but I didnt see this error anywhere. Can anyone help me solving this.
Plese let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: have you added "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29" in your dev devDependencies

Comment: yes i have this: "@angular-devkit/core": "*" 
@HrishikeshKale

Comment: i think you need to uninstall cli clean cache and then again install with the latest version and then use ng update for this, npm uninstall -g angular-cli then npm cache clean and then npm install -g @angular/cli then upgrade it to latest npm install @angular/cli@latest and then you can use ng update to upgrade config files