# How to update angular 2 or upper version project to a latest version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In my case, I have an angular 4 full project. Now I need to convert that to angular 6. is it possible or not. if possible can it do through CLI?

Comment: I downvoted this question, because a quick web search for "Angular update 4 to 6" provides a link to the Angular update website as the first result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Want to upgrade project from Angular v5 to Angular v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970553/want-to-upgrade-project-from-angular-v5-to-angular-v6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to upgrade your project. Angular has official documentation for the same. The complications of upgrade depends on which version you are upgrading from and how your project has been build. You can also follow official documentation of the same at:
https://update.angular.io/