# Upgrading from angular 5.2 to angular 6.1

Tags: angular, npm, upgrade

I am currently on node 8.11 and using VS code. The project was developed in 5.2.5 and has been dormant for a bit. My project has the following modules.

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';

and angular/material

I would like to move to angular 9, trying per the oficial instructions was a massive failure on the upgrade page angular.io. So I am trying to do in small chunks now. But that isn't going well.
Wondering if it would be better just to directly upgrade to node 10 or node 12 and create a new project from scratch in angular 9 and move the components over one by one, allowing me to update it. Note: I am not an expert in angular 9, but fairly comfortable with angular 5.2. What do you recommend?

One thing that would have hugely helped is if after each step a clear indication was given of how to know that it has succeeded, so we don't just accidentaly run the next step. Things appear to have worked but they haven't.

Current status:
After trying several instructions, I was trying steps outlined in this :
[Want to upgrade project from Angular v5 to Angular v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970553/want-to-upgrade-project-from-angular-v5-to-angular-v6)

On step 2 in the v5 to v6 section :
"Update Angular cli globally and locally, and migrate the old configuration .angular-cli.json to the new angular.json format by running the following:"
I am at this step : 
ng update @angular/cli@6.0.0
               (I decided to be specific about the version. Think I remember 6.1 had too many issues)

I still see angular-cli.json, and no angular.json.

What is supposed to have happened? How do I know if has it happened?

Or atleast - what is the fix? Is this good enough for me to proceed to next step : 
ng update @angular/core@6.0.0? 
I am planning to do this individually for each of the modules that exist in my project.

Let me know if I can provide any other info to clarify.

Thanks -- in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First update your node to the latest LTS version.

Then update angular cli globally by running these commands:

npm uninstall -g angular-cli || npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install @angular/cli@latest

Then in you project

run these commands:

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
ng update --all

Comment: do i need to remove the node modules folder rm node_modules, before doing any of the steps?

Comment: could not run npm cache clean. I was asked to run npm cache verify.

Comment: Did the step you recommend. When I did "ng update @angular/cli @angular/core"
ng : The term 'ng' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ng:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @meow run this command ng i -g @angular/cli before running ng update. The error term 'ng' is not recognized is because angular cli is not installed globally.